# Is it possible to allow the user to specify what file is to be downloaded in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, cordova

I'm developing an iPhone app (using JavaScript, HTML and PhoneGap/Cordova on Xcode) which on the click of a button downloads a file from dropbox and allows the user to read it into `<p>` tags. This all works but only when i specify the URL the programme is to follow to a specific file. I want the user to be able to chose their own file and download it to the app to be read. The code i currently have is;

```
 function downloadfile() {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/readme.txt");

        fileTransfer.download(
                uri,
                '/Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/AF96D141-0CE5-4D60-9FA8-8A8F9A999C81/Documents/readme.txt',
                function(entry) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                              alert("File Downloaded. Click 'Read Downloaded File' to see text");
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                }
        );
    }

    function readDownloadedFile() {
        myFileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: false, exclusive: false}, gotDownloadFileEntry, fail);
        $('#mytext').load('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/readme.txt', function(){
                                                                                console.log("read is done");
                                                                            });
    }

    function gotDownloadFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        console.log(fileEntry);
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }
```

If it is possible to allow the user to specify the file to be downloaded, how could i alter the code to do so? I'm fairly new to iPhone development so any help at all would be great :)

This is the HTML for the buttons in case you need it;

```
    <button onclick="downloadfile();">Download Dropbox File</button>
    <button onclick="readDownloadedFile();">Read Downloaded File</button>
```

Comment: You can pass the file URL as parameter to the `downloadfile(fileUrl)` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an input field to allow the users to specify the url they want to download.

```
<input type="text" id="toDl"/>
```

Then in your downloadFile() method you do:

```
var fileUrl = document.getElementById("toDl").value;
```

to get the url you want to download.

Comment: by the way - would it be possible to help me alter the rest of my code around this? I can also remove the file thats been downloaded, retrieve metadata about it and read the file into `<p>` tags.